# Why does using named imports makes the build smaller in size with material-ui?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I wish to understand why

```
import { RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';
```

webpack output is: `[./src/App.js] 2.32 KiB {main} [built]`

whereas the output for

```
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
```

is: `[./src/App.js] 2.4 KiB {main} [built]`

Yeah the question is not actually about Material-UI, but it's more about the import usage.

Comment: Isn't it called de-structuring?

Comment: Probably because of tree shaking. The default import/export depends on more things than the named import/export. Note that these are not equivalent. They are importing different values.

Comment: Have you diffed the bundles to see what is different?